# LIKE operator not supported in arango search view

Tags: arangodb, aql, arangojs, arangodb-foxx

Arango Search does not seem to support LIKE operator.
Other supported operators are working fine.

Tried this AQL:

```
FOR s IN searchView
SEARCH s.name LIKE "somesubstring"
RETURN s
```

But it gives an error saying:

> Query: AQL: not implemented: Unable to evaluate loop variable 's' as a
> part of ArangoSearch noncompliant expression
> 'LIKE([$0.name,"somesubstring"])' (exception location:
> C:\vm04-windows\oskar\work\ArangoDB\arangod\IResearch\IResearchExpressionContext.cpp:62)
> (while executing) (exception location:
> C:\vm04-windows\oskar\work\ArangoDB\arangod\RestHandler\RestCursorHandler.cpp:298)

Referred this: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/search/

Other supported operators are working fine.

How do we achieve this in Arango search view?
LIKE operator or mimicking the same behavior.

Issue reference: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/11176

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE (introduced in v3.7.0), also NOT LIKE`
The Alpha Version is Out now. You can test.